# How to keep a modal open in an if statement in template

Tags: django

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Order Completed</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>


{% if accepted_order %}
  <div class="collapse" id="collapseAcceptedCreatorOrders">
    <div class="card card-body">
      <h1>Buyer: <a href="{% url 'buyer_page'%}">{{ accepted_order }}</a></h1>
        <a href="{% url 'dashboard' %}">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
            Mark As Bought
          </button>
        </a>
        <a href="{% url 'dashboard_withdraw_order' %}"><button>Withdraw</button></a>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

I am trying to show a modal when a user clicks a button, inside this `if` statement. The only issue is when the button is clicked, the modal pops up for a split second and then disappears. When I use the button outside of the `if` statement it works fine, but I need to use it in the `if` statement. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, I figured it out. When the {% url ... %} command in the template is run, apparently, that refreshes the page, which I didn't know. So, all I did was add that portion in the modal. Basically, instead of encasing the button that opens the modal (that says "Mark as Bought") in a link that runs the logic. I just put a button in the if statement that then opens the modal, and inside the modal is where the logic is run.